# How to redirect a domain and its links to another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to `Redirect` from

- www.foo.com/ to www.bar.com/.
- www.foo.com/value to www.bar.com/value

I tried the following without success

```
Redirect 302 /(value) http://bar.com/$1
```

It doesn't work and throws a not found error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect Directive will not work for this issue, You need to use the RedirectMatch  instead.

Try this in your htaccess

```
 RedirectMatch 302 ^/(.*?)/?$  http://bar.com/$1
```